# Send multiple ARP requests with different source MAC

Tags: arp, ubuntu-20.04

Can I send a flood of ARP requests with multiple random source MAC addresses using Ubuntu 20.04 to a single destination IP address?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: I have an ubuntu machine running version 20.04 that I am wondering if I can send from it multiple arp requests each with a different random MAC to a single IP.